# Why my (click) event, that i wrote in a tr doesn't work?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, bootstrap-5

I wrote this code, when I click on the row of the table (tr tag) it doesn't do anything, I can't understand why...

```
readDetails(){
    this.router.navigate(['/dettaglio-contributivo']);
    console.log("There it is")
  }
```

This is the method in the component.ts

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of tableData" (click)="readDetails()">
    <td class="text-start">{{item.enteImpositore}}</td>
    <td class="text-start">VIA MONS CECE</td>
    <td class="text-start">CIMITILE</td>
    <td class="text-start">{{item.tributo}}</td>
    <td class="text-end">{{item.identificativo}}</td>
    <td class="text-end">{{item.anno}}</td>
    <td class="text-end">{{item.ruolo}}</td>
    <td class="text-end">1.320</td>
    <td class="text-end">0,00</td>
    <td class="text-end">468,04</td>
    <td class="text-end">852,45</td>
</tr>
```

And this is the code in the component.html
Either the console.log doesn't work

I tried to modify the method with something from chatGPT and other sites but nothing happen, also wrote the app-routing.module:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  {
    path: '',
    component: LayoutComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'posizione-contributiva', component: PosizioneContributivaComponent },
      { path: 'dettaglio-contributivo/:id', component: DettaglioContributivoComponent}
    ]
  }
];
```

Comment: To summarize swinne's answer, "routing paths must match". Therefore, experiment with your above code by either removing the `\:id` part in your route path, or provide the expected `id` part in your navigation like `this.router.navigate(['/dettaglio-contributivo', 1]);`.

Answer (score 1):

So, if I understand, you are in a route `<YOURSITE>/`. This route calls the layout component.

In this component:
If you click on the `<tr>` attribute, you must launch the method `ReadDetails()`. This method go to an other route : `<YOURSITE>/detagglio-contributivo/` and display a log.

**But** if I read your main routing file, there are **no** routes like this. The **only** route for this url is with the `:id`

So, you must declare it on your method. And for the console.log, I'm not sure but I think the best is to declare before the navigate.

Answer (score 1):

It worked! It was my error 'cause, his:

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of tableData" (click)="readDetails()">
    <td class="text-start">{{item.enteImpositore}}</td>
    <td class="text-start">VIA MONS CECE</td>
    <td class="text-start">CIMITILE</td>
    <td class="text-start">{{item.tributo}}</td>
    <td class="text-end">{{item.identificativo}}</td>
    <td class="text-end">{{item.anno}}</td>
    <td class="text-end">{{item.ruolo}}</td>
    <td class="text-end">1.320</td>
    <td class="text-end">0,00</td>
    <td class="text-end">468,04</td>
    <td class="text-end">852,45</td>
</tr>
```

This  wasn't write good because of the *ngFor so it wasn't displayed and I was clicking on other  without the (click)...

Sorry for waisting your time answering me but thank you all!